# Is there a way to decompose and compose Korean words to/from the individual consonants/vowels?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cjk, ime

I'm looking for a function that is able to convert a string from "ㅂㅏㅇㅇㅏㄷㅣ" to "방아디".

I've been stuck on this for a week now. I've found user-created python functions that do exactly what I want: https://github.com/jonghwanhyeon/hangul-jamo , https://github.com/bluedisk/hangul-toolkit , etc.
but unity does not support python, and I need to interface with C# code.

Does anyone know of such a thing for C#?

Thanks everyone~

Comment: This question may not receive the responses you are hoping for.  "Is there a way to...." is a rather vague question that is essentially a yes/no answer, which is surely not what you really want to ask.  Looking on into the question body, you state that you are looking for a library, then point to libraries written in other languages as examples.  Unfortunately, Asking for libraries is beyond the scope of the Q/A purpose of the site, and people rarely answer questions asking for libraries with a huge code dump.

Comment: Hi, aloau, why don't you use your first [example](https://github.com/jonghwanhyeon/hangul-jamo) and translate it into C#? With 124 lines, it won't take that much time.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used a code I have found in GitHub that was working great for english-italian, and it's this one https://gist.github.com/grimmdev/979877fcdc943267e44c

I also know another plugin which is more complex but can translate more efficiently : https://github.com/bbepis/XUnity.AutoTranslator

If you can't achieve a Korean translation in this way you should try a System Language class like in this example: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1196793/best-practice-for-multiple-languages.html

With the last method you will Always be able to translate but you need to translate word per word and maybe it's not what you are searching for

Comment: oh sorry I'm not looking for translation from/to korean. actually i'm looking for something that can parse individual korean consonants and vowels (in unicode, the characters are in the hangul jamo block).

basically for example, when you type "ㅂㅏㅇㅇㅏㄷㅣ" on a keyboard, it shows up as "방아디" automatically with an IME, but i'm trying to convert it directly.
thanks for trying to help though! :)